# Obtener URL solicitante en una petición API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, http, url, curl

Mi pregunta es cencilla: **estoy tratando de acceder a la url desde la cual se llamó a mi API en PHP**.

Es decir, si el usuario de la API ejecuta un cUrl u otro método hacia mi API desde la URL "http://url-usuario.com/" yo quiero obtener en mi API la url "http://url-usuario.com/".

¿Alguien sabe cómo realizar esto?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

*Título alternativo: Obtener url desde la que se llama a mi API en PHP*

Answer (score 2):

Ese dato, si viene, está en la superglobal [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Específicamente, las entradas `HTTP_REFERER` y `HTTP_ORIGIN` equivalen a los headers `referer` y `origin`, respectivamente.

**El referer** contiene lo que tú quieres:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
// http://url-usuario.com/links_recomendados/ficha_maximiliano_web
```

Pero no siempre lo vas a recibir. El browser decide al respecto (ej, no lo manda para visitas desde un sitio https a un sitio http), el usuario puede decidir no enviarlos si abre el navegador usando `chrome.exe  --no-referrers` , y la página misma desde donde viene el visitante puede evitar que el browser envíe esa cabecera usando [CSP Referrer Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). (nótese que la palabra es `Referrer`, pero hace 30 años alguien metió mal el dedo y el header quedó como `Referer`)

El header **origin** se envía cuando hay una petición `POST` o la petición va por `fetch` o `ajax`. Este header no tiene la ruta sino solamente el host de origen:

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
// http://url-usuario.com
```

Con eso protegen un poco más la privacidad del usuario y al mismo tiempo permiten que el sitio que recibe el request pueda filtrar desde dónde le están enviando un request de borrar la base de datos, porque nunca se sabe.

Con el CSP Referrer Policy que mencioné, el sitio de origen puede definir que el referer se envía, pero contiene lo mismo que el origin.

Además de que pueden venir vacíos, ninguno de los dos headers es realmente confiable. En curl puedes hacer

```
curl 'https://www.maximiliano_web.com/promociones' \
  -H 'Origin: https://www.que.te.importa' \
  -H 'Referer: https://www.no.quiero.enviar/desde.donde.vengo'
```